# PHP mail reading mime boundary as part of the mail body

Tags: php, email, email-attachments

```
$home = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
$hostUrl = 'https://my-domain.com';

$tmpName = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
$result = time().'-'.substr(sha1(mt_rand()),0,10);
$target = "/uploaded-files/".$result.".pdf";
$filePath = $home.$target;
$fileUrl = $hostUrl.$target;
move_uploaded_file($tmpName, $filePath);

$textMsg = '<p>Hi! Kanayo Austin</p>';
$textMsg .= '<p>Your request to print your JAMB Result Slip was successful and below is a PDF attachment of your JAMB Result Slip.</p>';

$textMsg .= '<p>You can also login to your account to download your JAMB Result Slip<a href="https://my-domain.com/login/">Login</a></p>';
$textMsg .= '<p>Need to access more of our services? <a href="https://my-domain.com/">Access More</a></p>';
$subject = "JAMB Result Slip";
$templateUrl = $hostUrl.'/mail-templates/default.php?title='.urlencode($subject).'&text='.urlencode($textMsg);
$msg = file_get_contents($templateUrl, true);

$file = fopen($filePath, 'rb');
$fileContent = fread($file, filesize($filePath));
fclose($file);
$data = chunk_split(base64_encode($fileContent));
$separator = md5(time());
$mimeBoundary = "==Multipart_Boundary_x{$separator}x";
$headers = "From: Grafil Computers <noreply@grafil-computers.com> \r\n";
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0 \r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; \r\n";
$headers .= " boundary=\"{$mimeBoundary}\" \r\n";
$message = "--{$mimeBoundary}\n";
$message .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=\"UTF-8\" \r\n";
$message .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit \r\n\r\n";
$message .= $msg  . " \r\n";
$message .= "--{$mimeBoundary} \r\n";
$message .= "Content-Type: application/pdf; \r\n";
$message .= " name=\"Result-Slip.pdf\" \r\n";
$message .= "Content-Disposition: attachment; \r\n";
$message .= " filename=\"Result-Slip.pdf\" \r\n";
$message .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64{$data} \r\n";
$message .= "--{$mimeBoundary}--";

mail('name@email.com', $subject, $message, $headers);
```

I use the above code to send emails to my users with an attached PDF file.

But the issue is that after the message body, the mail doesn't acknowledge the mime boundary. It reads it as part of the message body therefore showing all the message configurations and the file's base64 as plain text See image below:

[image: Screenshot]

You can see (marked with red) the mime boundary with other contents showing as plain text after my main html message body

So the PDF file doesn't show as file but as text instead. I really don't know what I'm doing wrong because I cross-checked my code with other codes from StackOverflow and other websites and they are all corresponding

**Note:** All PHP variables are working fine

Comment: You should probably use a library like PHPMailer, it will create attachments properly.

Comment: Agreed...use a ready made library for this. No need to make your life difficult

Comment: Seems very arbitrary, that you put `\n` behind the boundary the first time, and `\r\n` the second.